# Sql distinct group by rows

Tags: sql

Can anyone help me to know how to build sql query for following table to get distinct rows (based on name and date) with latest date.

```
Date               Name     Score

2011-06-16 10:30   Johan    36    
2010-12-09 08:52   Thomas   32
2012-04-25 15:14   Jak      56
2008-09-07 11:57   Jak      64
2012-02-28 13:22   Jan      23 
2011-01-11 12:08   Thomas   22      
2008-10-06 12:22   Kane     54
```

As a result, the query will show rows 1, 3, 6, 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - Select unique rows from a group of results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339624/sql-select-unique-rows-from-a-group-of-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
select date, name, score
from temp t1
where date = (select max(date) from temp where t1.name = temp.name)
```

see a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4eec6/1) with a demo.

Answer (score 2):

I'm contributing something, because of the issue of duplicates on the maximum date.  All the above return all the duplicates.  It is possible that the questioner still only wants one of the rows.

```
SELECT date, name, score
FROM (select *,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) as seqnum
      from table a
     ) a
WHERE seqnum = 1
```

This enumerates the rows, starting by the latest date counting backwards.  It then chooses one of the dates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your RDMS doesn't support window functions,

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT name,MAX(date) as max_date -- date field may need escaping
  FROM table1 a
  GROUP BY name
)b ON (b.name = a.name AND a.date=b.max_date)
```

**Update**

Following **Dems** comment, if date+name is not unique, but you want to see a name just once,

```
SELECT c.name,c.date, MAX(c.score) as max_score
FROM
(
 SELECT a.* 
 FROM table1 a
 INNER JOIN 
 (
  SELECT name,MAX(date) as max_date -- date field may need escaping
  FROM table1 a
  GROUP BY name
 )b ON (b.name = a.name AND a.date=b.max_date)
)c
```

Comment: +1 : Note, however, that this does *assume* that for each name, the date field is unique.

Comment: @Dems : I agree, but I believe it's quite legitimate assumption in this case (name +date is unique)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work...

```
SELECT date, name, score
FROM table a
WHERE date = (
    SELECT MAX(date)
    FROM table b
    WHERE a.name = b.name
)
```

Comment: +1 : Note, however, that this does *assume* that for each name, the date field is unique.

Answer (score -1):

```
select convert(varchar,date,103) as name_date, name from table1 where convert(varchar, date, 103) = (select convert(varchar,max(date),103) as n_date from table1)
```

this is when time is not be considered in mssql database sql format

Comment: -1 : Conversion to strings for DATETIME manipulation will always get a -1 from me.  Sorry.

Comment: sad that my answer came to ur perview